# Is there an easy way to clone a SQL-instance between projects in Google cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm wondering if there exists an easy way to clone sql-instances between projects in Google Cloud. I understand that i can export the data to a bucket see img_1, but i find that a bit cumbersome ..

[image: img_1]

If anyone has a easy way to do this, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no “quick” way to Clone your SQL instance between projects. A clone operation essentially needs to bundle these 3 operations into 1, and hence why it is possible to have a clone within a project but not outside the project.

- The data from the origin
- The instance to receive said data
- How to transfer this data

A [Cloud SQL clone](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/clone-instance) can only occur within the project. What you are looking for is a backup and [restore to a different project](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/backup-recovery/restoring#projectid), effectively cloning the instance but manually.

There is an open feature request open for this type of request. I suggest that you “+1” yourself on that so that you are kept up to date on the development of the feature.

If you want to have “clone” your instance to a different project, you have 2 options:

1. SQL dump > GCS > Import dump from GCS into Cloud SQL
2. Restore your instance to a different project

Feel free to ask questions as you wish.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are looking for a different approach:

We can **also** recover a backup from an instance in a project to a different project, as docs says [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/backup-recovery/restoring#projectid). This is an approach that is not automated but essentially manual.

Comment: Should be accepted answer!