# Migrate GCP CloudSQL and BigQuery Database

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql

I have a one time use case to copy the data and the schema of the existing databases of CloudSQL and BigQuery from one GCP Project to another one. Is there any preferred way of achieving this other than creating the schema and the databases and writing scripts to copy all the existing data?

Comment: There is no 1-step solution. See [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64590750/is-there-an-easy-way-to-clone-a-sql-instance-between-projects-in-google-cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64590750/is-there-an-easy-way-to-clone-a-sql-instance-between-projects-in-google-cloud)

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL you can use [Database migration service](https://cloud.google.com/database-migration). For bigQuery, you can use [data transfer service](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs)